# String is not converting in url properly (Objective - c)

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code

```
NSString *urlString = [[self.listContainer.list objectAtIndex:1].items objectAtIndex:0].placeHolder;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url];
```

Here my urlstring is not nil but i don't know why url is nil.. Can anyone please help me figure it out.

Comment: would you share me the string url you're using?

Comment: Could you print `urlString`? There are plenty of possible issue. For instance, if there is a "space", or another invalid char, `url` will be nil.

Comment: Yes i can print urlString ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the spaces before turning it into a url.

```
let urlString = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/LogoServer/resource/iOS/logos/3XD/Abstract/Logo 100/Holder.jpg"  
print("urlString: \(urlString)")  

var escapedString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())  
print("escapedString!: \(escapedString!)")  

let orginUrl = NSURL(string: escapedString!)  
print("orginUrl: \(orginUrl!)")
```

```
NSString *url = @"http://127.0.0.1:8080/LogoServer/resource/iOS/logos/3XD/Abstract/Logo 100/Holder.jpg";
NSString* encodedUrl =
    [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
     NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:encodedUrl];
[self.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url];
```

I hope this compiles, my obj-c is really rusty.

Comment: CAn you please give me a objective c version. I am having trouble to understand it.

Comment: `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` exists also in Objective-C. And it's rather `URLPathAllowedCharacterSet`

Comment: Obvviously OP will write some testing code that checks both valid and invalid strings to make sure the code works as it should.

Comment: can you please remove the url from your comment? i mean the link i shared with you.